# Promise flow control

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have three resources:

1. Hotel
2. Address
3. Image

A hotel can have one address but many images. While saving all three at once first I need to save hotel details and then taking the hotel id I should associate it with address and each images and save them one by one.

Now, I think that I can save images and address in parallel and if something fails I should be able to roll back the transaction. While saving images I know I can use `Promise.all`.

What should be the Promise chain flow while saving all the resources given the relationship constraints.

Let me be more clear I want something like:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

Where bot B and C get the same value returned by A.

Comment: Sounds like you can merge the address saving together with all the image savings in the same `Promise.all()`

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service. The objective is to help you fix **your code** when it isn't working as expected, not do your work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function createHotel(data) {
  // Create your hotel
}

function createAddresses(addresses, hotelId) {
  // Create addresses with hotelId
}

function createImages(images, hotelId) {
  // Create images with hotelId
}

createHotel({ name: 'Test' })  // I don't know your structure, this is just placeholder
  .then(function(hotel) {
    return Promise.all([
      createAddresses(addresses, hotel.id),
      createImages(images, hotel.id)
    ]);
  })
  .then(function() {
    // Everything was created successfully
    console.log('Done!');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // Rollback here
    console.log(err);
  })
```

Comment: I am surprised too, anyways what if instead of `Done` I need the newly created hotel id?